# manipulation of a function in typescript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

```
export const wrapCountable = (func: Function): Function => {
    let result: Function & { __times?: number } = () => {
        //result.__times = result.__times || 0
        result.__times++
        let value = null
        try {
            value = func()
        } catch (e) {
            throw e
        }
        return value
    }
    result.__times = 0
    return result
}
```

This function will wrap another function which is passed in as a parameter.

The problem is that when `strictNullChecks` mode is set to `true`, there will be an error in IDE.

[image]

The only solution to this error I can come up with is to add this line:

```
result.__times = result.__times || 0
```

However I don't think it's a perfect solution. What is the proper way then?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't realize that `result.__times` will definitely be defined by the time the arrow function in `result` is called.  If you would prefer not to change the emitted JavaScript, you can use the [non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) `!` to tell the compiler that you are smarter than it is and that `result.__times` will be defined:

```
export const wrapCountable = (func: Function): Function => {
    let result: Function & { __times?: number } = () => {
        result.__times!++ // notice the ! here
        let value = null
        try {
            value = func()
        } catch (e) {
            throw e
        }
        return value
    }
    result.__times = 0
    return result
}
```

That will suppress the error.  It isn't type-safe, though... you could comment out the `result.__times = 0` line and the error will still be suppressed.  Type assertions including `!` make it possible to lie to the compiler.  Still, I'd expect that in this case you can make an informed decision to use an assertion.

That being said I'd probably collapse your function to something like

```
const wrapCountable = <T>(func: () => T) => {
    const result = Object.assign(() => {
        result.__times++;
        return func();
    }, { __times: 0 });
    return result;
}

const eighteen = wrapCountable(() => 18);
// const eighteen: (() => number) & {__times: number}
console.log(eighteen()); // 18
console.log(eighteen()); // 18
console.log(eighteen.__times); // 2
```

with a generic `T` so you don't lose the type of the return value, and with `Object.assign()` so you don't have to allow `__times` to be `undefined`, and without that `try`/`catch` block which doesn't seem to be doing anything (re-`throw`-ing the same exception is a no-op, right?).

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!